# MUI Radio pass the label and value in onChange when selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

I'm using reactjs, I have a MUI RadioGroup component from which I want to pass the label together of the selected value.

My Radio Button Code

```
<RadioGroup
    aria-label="am-time-in"
    value={state.AM_time_in_value}
    name="radio-buttons-group"
    onChange={onChangeRadioAMIN}
>
    {
        state.AM_timelogs_IN ?
            state.AM_timelogs_IN.map((radio) => (
                <Tooltip
                    title={
                        <>
                            <Typography variant="caption">
                                {`Scan Location: ${radio.scan_location}`}
                            </Typography>
                            <br />
                            <Typography variant="caption">
                                {`Scanned By: ${radio.scanned_by}`}
                            </Typography>
                        </>
                    }
                >
                    <FormControlLabel value={radio.time_check.split(',')[1].slice(1)} control={<Radio size="small" />} label={radio.time_standard} item={radio} />
                </Tooltip>
            )) : null
    }
</RadioGroup>
```

My `onchange` function:

```
const onChangeRadioAMIN = (event, value) => {   
        console.log(event);     
        event.persist();        
        setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            AM_time_in_value: value,
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `id` field to identify between your options:

```
const options = [
  {
    id: 0,
    scan_location: value_1,
    scanned_by: value_2,
    time_check: value_3,
    time_standard: value_4,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    scan_location: value_1,
    scanned_by: value_2,
    time_check: value_3,
    time_standard: value_4,
  },
  ...
];
```

And pass the `id` to the `value` prop of `FormControlLabel`, the `change` handler will receive the `id` when the user changes the option. Note that you cannot pass the option object to [`value`](https://mui.com/api/radio/#:%7E:text=for%20more%20details.-,value,-any) because it will be casted to string so you only get `[object Object]` otherwise:

```
{options.map((o) => (
  <FormControlLabel
    value={o.id} // <---- pass a primitive id value, don't pass the whole object here
    control={<Radio />}
    label={o.time_standard}
  />
))}
```

You can then find the selected option object from that `id` with all the fields you need:

```
<RadioGroup
  onChange={(e, value) => {
    const id = parseInt(value, 10);
    const option = options.find((o) => o.id === id);
    // setState
  }}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]